# actionscript 2 functions for detecting when no keys are pressed

Tags: button, keyboard, key, actionscript-2, detection

I would like to know how to detect when no buttons are pressed on a movieclip,
such as

```
if (no keys are pressed){
```

this.gotoAndStop("idle");
}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you expand your question as you expand your purpose of what you achieve, maybe I can present a more in depth solllution ... ;) I can not imagine why you need a no buttons pressed event. Anyway you can use this code snippet.

```
//This belongs to no button pressed event.
    var def = 0;
    var keyListener:Object = new Object();
    keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
       def = 1;
    };
    keyListener.onKeyUp = function() {
       def = 0;
    };
    Key.addListener(keyListener);



//First Part for the whole movie clip
    _root.onEnterFrame = function (){
        trace(def);
        if(def == 1){
        this.gotoAndStop("idle");
        }
    }
```